# PHP variable containing MySQL record is cut off

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP variable app_trip_gpx which contains a string with uploaded gpx data.

- On my local environment the string is handled fine. PHP 5.6 MYSQL 5.6
- On my production environment the string is cut off after many lines. PHP 5.4 MYSQL 5.5

In the database the string is okay on local and production.

Checked PHP memory 256 MB should be fine. Increased MySQL packet size. I am out of ideas :-)

Comment: Is this variable sent by Get method?

Comment: How many bytes is it after truncation?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No it is not sent by Get method. It is is a variable containing a MySQL record that is read from the database via Eloquent. I first thought Eloquent could be the problem but on my local environment it is working fine. The Eloquent versions are the same on the local and production environment.

Comment: PHP does not randomly “cut off” variable values at some point and without any error. Without seeing what code you are using, there is probably no way of answering this.

Comment: Excellent question Phil. I think maybe your question is pointing me in the right direction. I just did a byte count on two different outputs and the were both 1,048,594 bytes.

Comment: @CBroe I am getting no errors in the log files. It is a Laravel 4.2 website and I am using Eloquent to fetch the data. The actual code: $trip->app_trip_gpx. Where Trip is a model. It works fine for records that are less then 1MB. I don't think the PHP code is the problem. Maybe MySQL memory but I can not find the right setting.

Comment: _“I just did a byte count on two different outputs and the were both 1,048,594 bytes”_ – so _how_ are they different then, if the byte size is identical?

Comment: I think you did not read the question very well @CBroe. The original strings are both longer but they are truncated.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The solution was adding:

'options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 16777216),

to config (database.connections mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The solution was adding:

'options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 16777216)

to my laravel database config (database.connections mysql)